How to programmatically disable battery optimization on Expo React Native?
Good day.
It's a funny question, but because of it the task manager falls off. Please help.
How can I programmatically disable battery optimization or send the user to a page where they can disable it?
I tried googling, but it didn't bring any results other than a manual on how to turn it off manually

Without more detail about why you want to disable it, see https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby and https://dontkillmyapp.com/

As of my knowledge, this is not directly supported. However, you can achieve this by ejecting from the managed workflow (using Expo's "bare" workflow) and then integrating native modules or using a specific library for handling battery optimization settings.
